# How to create and pass multiarray in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How to create and pass multiarray in Twig?

```
{{ include('box.html.twig', {multi: {aaa: bbb, ccc: ddd}}) }}
```

Is good but I would like have to many elements in variable multi:

```
{{ include('box.html.twig', {multi: {aaa: bbb, ccc: ddd}, {aaa: eee, ccc: fff}}) }}
```

It doesn't work.

```
{{ include('box.html.twig', {multi: {{aaa: bbb, ccc: ddd}, {aaa: eee, ccc: fff}}}) }}
```

and:

```
{{ include('box.html.twig', {multi: [{aaa: bbb, ccc: ddd}, {aaa: eee, ccc: fff}}]) }}
```

Also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
{% include 'box.html.twig' with {'multi': {{'aaa': 'bbb', 'ccc': 'ddd'}, {'aaa': 'eee', 'ccc': 'fff'}}} %}
```

For more information check 
https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

**Note**:if you are using without quotes php will consider as defined word.

Comment: In your example I have error: "A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{". ". I use Symfony 2.6.13.

Comment: In your version try with double Curly brackets

Comment: Can you give me example? I tried: {% include 'box.html.twig' with {"multi": {{"aaa": "bbb", "ccc": "ddd"}, {"aaa": "eee", "ccc": "fff"}}} %} and I have still error: "A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{". ".

Comment: Try with {{ instead of {%